# Using Global variables in Threads in Python

Tags: python, global-variables, python-multithreading

I am in a situation where i want to put a thread in a loop depending on a variable which is being changed in one of the called function in the thread.Here is what i want.

```
error= 0

while( error = 0)
    run_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_test,args=(some arguments))

if ( error = 0)
    continue
else:
    break
```

Now run test calls a function say A and A calls B and B calls C.

```
def A()
      B()
def B()
     c()

def c()
    global error
    error = 1
```

This is what i want to do but i cant work this out. If i try to print error i get an error in code.

Can anybody please help me on this?

i am a beginner and need to get over this

Comment: please format your code as syntactically valid Python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Threads and Global variabes in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202750/threads-and-global-variabes-in-python)

Comment: You have several syntax errors in your code and you did not tell us what error you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
error = False

def A():
      B()

def B():
     c()

def c():
    global error
    error = True

def run_test():
    while not error:
        A()
    print "Error!"

import threading
run_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_test,args=())
run_thread.start()
```

However, its better to subclass thread and re-implement run(), and also use exceptions:

```
def A():
    raise ValueError("Bad Value")

import threading
class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.stop = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop:
            A() #Will raise, which will stop the thread 'exceptionally'

    def stop(self): #Call from main thread, thread will eventually check this value and exit 'cleanly'
        self.stop = True
```

Comment: Thnaks for the reply .Sorry but i was not completely articulate about my problem. Well i am running two threads in the while loop which makes this solution not useful for me I need the check on one thread error but if there is one then i need to rerun both the threads. so i cannot loop in the function but i need to loop around the threads.Hope i am making clear this time. i cannot answer my question because of the form rules otherwise i could have rewritten the code description

Comment: Threads are not stoppable; if you're spawning threads in a while loop you'll be spawning one for each iteration. If that's what you want, go for it, but remember to call the thread's start() function. Note that you'll be busy creating threads as fast as possible, without stopping, unless you implement a wait condition. Perhaps try thread.join()?

Comment: i do not want to stop the threads. All i want is at the end of the threads, to check if there was an error and if there was then just rerun both the threads.....Also i am doing thread.join(). Is there a way i can do it?/....and i have to loop around the threads. So the given solution does not work for me

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question? while; t1(); t1.start(); t2(), t2.start(); t1.join(); t2.join()